# Spring Integration Aggregator Throttler

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have one message `SomeMessage` that looks like this:

```
class SomeMessage{
 id,
 title
}
```

Currently, I aggregate messages based on id. Messages are released after 10 seconds.

```
.aggregate(
            a ->
                a 
                .outputProcessor(messageProcessor())
                .messageStore(messageGroupStore())
                .correlationStrategy(correlationStrategy())
                .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                .groupTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)))
        .handle(amqpOutboundEndpoint)
```

What I need is a way to throttle messages based on `title` property. If `title=="A"`, it should still wait 10 seconds for aggregation; If `title=="B"` it should wait 60 seconds for aggregation and it should not be immediately sent to `amqpOutboundEndpoint` but it should have some throttling (eg. 30 seconds between every message that has `title=="B"`).

What would be the best way to do this? Is there something like throttling on `AmqpOutboundEndpoint`?

**UPDATE**

```
.groupTimeout(messageGroup -> {
                      if(anyMessageInGroupHasTitleB(messageGroup)){
                        return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(60);
                      }
                      else {
                        return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);
                      }
                    }))
        .route(
            (Function<SomeMessage, Boolean>) ec ->
            ec.getTitle().equals("B"),
        m -> m.subFlowMapping(true, sf ->
            sf.channel(channels -> channels.queue(1))
                .bridge(e -> e.poller(Pollers
                    .fixedDelay(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(1)
                ))
        ).subFlowMapping(false, IntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge))
    .handle(amqpOutboundEndpoint)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupTimeoutExpression()` instead of a fixed timeout...

```
payload.title == 'A' ? 10000 : 30000
```

Comment: thanks garry. that solves first part of the problem (aggregation interval). what about throttling? maybe i have not described correctly. I still aggregate by id but timeout/throttling decission is based on title.

Comment: Actually, the expression is evaluated against the `MessageGroup`, not the current message. The expression can be anything you want `@someBean.calculateTimeout(#root)` - so you can put your custom logic there to examine the group contents and return the timeout.

Comment: yes, but what if i have id:1;title:B and id:2;titleB. received at the same time. both messages will get delayed by 30 seconds in your example, but will be released together after 30 seconds. i need for first one to go after 30, but second to be throttled and sent after 60 (30 sec in between).

Comment: How about to use a `Delayer` for that your throttling requirements: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#delayer ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Is this going to delay all messages by, lets say 30sec, if I add them all at once? If I add 3 messages with `title==B` at the same time, 1st one should go immediately, 2nd one should be delayed 30s and 3rd one should be delayed 60s.

Comment: Hm. Doesn't look like an aggregator is what you need: you just don't build a message group. Consider to use a router based on that `title` to send one type of messages to one channel and another to different. For throttling like that I would consider to use a `QueueChannel` with `size = 1`, a `fixedDelay=30s` and poller with a `maxMessagesPerPoll = 1`. This way only one message is going to be pulled from the queue and the next one only after 30 seconds. Therefore a third one will go away after 60 seconds. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan that makes sense for me to be put after aggregator in this case. So if `title==A` - aggregate (with 10s delay) and send immediately to `AmqpOutboundEndpoint `. If `title==B` aggregate (with 30s delay) and send to `QueueChannel` with `size=1` and then from that poller to `AmqpOutboundEndpoint`. I guess this would work?

Comment: Why do you still need an aggregator? Are you really going to send all the `title==B` as one message, but after all those delays for them?

Comment: Not all with `title` but with same `id` and `title==B`. So `{id=1,title=A...otherProps1}` and `{id=1,title=A...otherProps2}` is aggregated and sent immediately and `{id=2,title=B...otherProps3}` and `{id=2,title=B...otherProps4}` is aggregated and sent immediatelly but `{id=3,title=B...otherProps5}` and `{id=3,title=B...otherProps6}` is aggregated but sent 30 seconds after `id=2`...

Comment: @GaryRussell is it correct behavior in `groupTimeoutExpression` to adjust time to the last one returned? e.g. if I have timeout set to 10 seconds, and I receive first aggregated message at time 00:00 and the next message at 00:05 and third message at 00:09, final aggregated message will be emitted at 00:19 (and not 00:10 as I think should happen)? Seems like every next message extends time window.

Comment: Hm. Sounds like `id=2` group has a control over `id=3`. Consider to introduce some control message which is going to be send to the aggregator after processing `id=2`. This marker message should be considered as a part of `id=3`. Therefore `id=3` won't release until that control message has arrived to this `id=3` group.

Comment: That is correct; you have to include `timestamp` (group creation time) in your expression if you want the timeout based on that. See `MessageGroup` javadocs.

Comment: @ArtemBilan that is the throttling I need - I guess I can just route after aggregation and if `title=A` goes directly, and if `title=B` goes to that Queue Poller. @GarryRussel - thanks, I'll check that.

Comment: Yes, that would work, too. You release groups independently, but don't let `title=B` to be pulled from the queue until the previous is processed.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I updated the question - tried using bridge with poller but now get that that subFlow is `is a SubscribableChannel (not pollable)`.

Comment: `sf.bridge()`. Place, a `.channel(channels -> channels.queue(1))` with option  before that `bridge()`

Comment: Thanks! works now with that and other `.subFlowMapping(false, IntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge))`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan do you know why if I use `defaultOutputToParentFlow()` instead of `.subFlowMapping(false, IntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge))` messages are not forwarded to parent flow (`amqpOutboundEndpoint `)?

Comment: You probably get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'false' available` exception, which you don't mention here. Consider to use a `.resolutionRequired(false)` to make that `default` working. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220020/discussion-between-bojan-vukasovic-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: We don't "chat" over here on SO. I would say that current your problem is over. For that router issue, please, consider to raise a new SO thread.

Comment: @ArtemBilan OK. I think I know what is the problem. `channels.queue(1)` here we allow only 1 message in queue and aggregator is getting locked because it cannot pass and release messages.

Comment: I don't think it is related to the router issue somehow....